# Need to download Ubuntu ISO, but getting "Invalid ISO" error message

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, usb, multi-boot, iso-image

[image]

I'm using a USB/DVD download tool within my current OS (Windows 7) for allowing Dual Boot functionality alongside Ubuntu. I downloaded Ubuntu off their main site and when I use the download tool, I get the error message as seen in my desktop screen shot. Anyone know why I'm getting this message?

Comment: You can't make a bootable USB device with Microsoft usb tool because they have only designed it for the Windows. Try [yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) and you will be able to create a bootable USB for Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft tool is only for Windows ISO's to make bootable. Try the tool from http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

I've always had good luck with it and it works for almost all major distros

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded it and I chose a source. It tried installing the ISO I had on my hard drive and USB, and it gave me the following statement: "This Linux is not in the compatibility list, however LinuxLive USB creator will try to use the same install parameters as for "Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal Quetzal (Unity/Gnome). In addition, step 3 says "Persistence" with the option to scroll MB's. What do I do here as this is unfamiliar territory for me. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're trying to use the USB key to install linux on a different partition, you can ignore the persistence part and turn it off, (it's just a read/write area of the key to store files on if you want a portable install of the ubuntu live cd). After that, hit the go button and then try to boot off the USB key.